# The algorithm problem: Unique Paths III. Using backtracing pattern in javascript and not work

Tags: javascript, algorithm, backtracking

On a 2-dimensional grid, there are 4 types of squares:

1 represents the starting square.  There is exactly one starting square.

2 represents the ending square.  There is exactly one ending square.

0 represents empty squares we can walk over.

-1 represents obstacles that we cannot walk over.

Return the number of 4-directional walks from the starting square to the ending square, that walk over every non-obstacle square exactly once.

> source：力扣（LeetCode）
> link：https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/unique-paths-iii

i'm trying to use backtrack pattern to solve this problem

here is my code

```
/**
 * @param {number[][]} grid
 * @return {number}
 */
var uniquePathsIII = function(grid) {
    let m = grid.length,
        n = grid[0].length;
    let start, targetIndex1,targetIndex2;
    let res = 0;
    let zero_counts = 0;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(grid[i][j] == 1){
                start = [i,j]
            }
            else if(grid[i][j] == 0){
                zero_counts += 1;
            }
            else if(grid[i][j] == 2){
                targetIndex1 = i;
                targetIndex2 = j;
            }
        }
    }

    const backtrace = (i, j, zero_count) => {
        if( i < 0 || i >= m || 
            j < 0 || j >= n || 
            grid[i][j] == -1 || zero_count < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(i == targetIndex1 && j == targetIndex2 ){
            if(zero_count == 0)
            {
                console.log("yes")
                res += 1;
            }
            return
        }
        
        grid[i][j] = -1;
        backtrace(i+1, j, zero_count - 1)
        backtrace(i-1, j, zero_count - 1)
        backtrace(i, j+1, zero_count - 1)
        backtrace(i, j-1, zero_count - 1)

        grid[i][j] = 0;
    }

    backtrace(start[0], start[1], zero_counts);

    return res;
};
```

test sample:

```
[[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,2,-1]]
```

expect result:
2

acutal result:
0

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simpler solution is to use [Depth First Search to solve Unique Paths III](https://ataiva.com/how-to-solve-unique-paths-iii-in-java/), as shown here.

The concept is that you take a point and then traverse in all directions until you hit an obstacle.

The guts are as follows:

```
int totalPaths = dfs(grid, x+1, y,   zero) +
                 dfs(grid, x,   y+1, zero) +
                 dfs(grid, x-1, y,   zero) +
                 dfs(grid, x,   y-1, zero);
```